# DropdownList DataSource c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have problem with `DropDownList`. I can manage to create 2 `DropDownList` where the 2nd one is dependent on the choice you make in the first but I can't get it to work with multiple lists.
I have AutoPostBack on true and

```
//OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddl_1_SelectedIndexChanged"> for ddl_2 and
//OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddl_2_SelectedIndexChanged"> for ddl_3

protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    var source1 = new List<ListItem>()
    {
        new ListItem("Test1"),
        new ListItem("Test2")
    };

    var source2 = new List<ListItem>()
    {
        new ListItem("Test3"),
        new ListItem("Test4")
    };

    var source3 = new List<ListItem>()
    {
        new ListItem("A"),
        new ListItem("B")
    };

    switch(this.ddl_1.SelectedValue)
    {
        case "1":
            this.ddl_2.DataSource = source1;
            break;
        case "2":
            this.ddl_2.DataSource = source2;
            break;
        case "3":
            this.ddl_2.DataSource = source3;
            break;
    }


    this.ddl_2.DataBind();

}

protected void DropDownList2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var source4 = new List<ListItem>()
    {
        new ListItem("C"),
        new ListItem("D")
    };

    switch (this.ddl_2.SelectedValue)
    {
        case "1":
            this.ddl_3.DataSource = source4;
            break;
    }

    this.ddl_3.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: what error you are getting/

Comment: that's the problem I don't get an error but when I want to try it out and I select first item on ddl 1 to get source1 in ddl2 and then take 1 in ddl2 to get source4 in ddl3 ddl3 just stays blank so I thought I might not have the right case there.

Comment: debug the code and check it. You will find the actual error.

Comment: I bet your `SelectedValue` is not "1", "2" or "3". Put a breakpoint on the `switch` statements. Then look at the `SelectedItem`.

Comment: so my `SelectedValue` on first switch is 1,2,3 that's fine but I don't even get to the point of the 2nd switch so that switch is the problem. I don't get any `SelectedValues` there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me take `source3` as an example here you have two list items, but you ware specified the `Text` property only. and Accessing the Value Property in the switch.

The `ListItem` is a class having two constructor, One will accepts `Text` and the second will accepts `Text` as well as `value` so What you need to do is:- make use of the second constructor to define the list items. So it will looks like the following:

```
var source3 = new List<ListItem>()
    {
        new ListItem("A","1"),
        new ListItem("B","2")
    };
```

So that we can say that `"1"` will be the value field for the Item `"A"` and "2" is for Item "B".

But in your case you need to identify the datasource. No problem i will suggest an option for that too. Let me re-define the `source3` like the following

```
var source3 = new List<ListItem>()
    {
        new ListItem("A","3A"),
        new ListItem("B","3B")
    };//Where 3 stands for source3
```

If so you need to replace the switch with `if..else..if` hence the conditions will be:

```
if(this.ddl_1.SelectedValue.ToString().Contains("3")){
    // assign Source 3 Here
}
else if (this.ddl_1.SelectedValue.ToString().Contains("2"))
{
    // assign Source 2 Here
}
// and so on
```

Comment: This works nicely for the first 2 Dropdownlists as well but still the ddl_3 stays blank and I don't get why

Comment: `protected void DropDownList2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var source4 = new List<ListItem>()
        {
            new ListItem("C","1C"),
            new ListItem("D","1D"),
            new ListItem("E","1E")
        };

        if (this.ddl_2.SelectedValue.ToString().Contains("1"))
        {
            this.ddl_3.DataSource = source4;
        }

        this.ddl_3.DataBind();
    }`

so I tried to take your example to ddl_3 to make it dependent on the choice of ddl_2

Comment: sorry for this horribly formated code :/

ddl_3 just stays blank I can't take any options there

Comment: Let me know what is the source bounded to `ddl_2.`

Comment: So I just tried out to create a 4th ddl and make it dependant on `ddl_2` and somehow that worked :D so I guess you saved me somehow =) thank you for your help. The problem was the Value in `ddl_2` had to contain the condition I set fo the if clause.